# Compare the above cell value and return alphabets

Tags: vba, excel

I am having two columns `Last Name` and `First Name`. Column `Last Name` contains real names and it may contain same names multiple times (if a name is repeating then it will be in the subsequent rows only and not elsewhere).

Requirement:

Now In the column `First Name` (its empty only), I need to capture alphabets based on the 'Last Name'. i.e. i am expecting the first name column to be filled with A || B || C || D||  if a last name contains 4 times. e.g.:

```
Lastname    Firstname
SMITH       A
SMITH       B
Conte       A
Conte       B
Watts       A
Watts       B
Speirs      A
Speirs      B
CONNOLLY    A
Austin      A
Austin      B
Austin      C
Austin      D
Austin      E
Austin      F
Austin      G
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and the problems you have encountered.  I would just check the cells above, and generate a letter depending on identity of last name, and the letter in in the first name column.

Comment: I have tried with nested if, but it didn't work...  to be precise.. if the last name contains SCOTT only once, then i need 'A' should be captured against SCOTT in first name column.   likewise if we have SCOTT four times, then the first name column should contain, A  || B || C || D

Comment: I don't see anything that you have tried.  As you know, this is not a free code-writing service, but exists to help you with your problems.  We need to see your attempts in order to help.

Comment: Found the answer myself.. thanks 'Ron' for forced me to dig the solution on my own;  Its working fine, but just tell me ... is there an alternate way... instead of many IFs...

=IF(E77<>E76,"A",IF(E77<>E75,"B",IF(E77<>E74,"C",IF(E77<>E73,"D",IF(E77<>E72,"E",IF(E77<>E71,"F",IF(E77<>E70,"G",IF(E77<>E69,"H",IF(E77<>E68,"I",IF(E77<>E67,"J",IF(E77<>E66,"K","")))))))))))

Comment: You could also look at my answer to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044496/rename-duplicates-with-random-alphabets-in-a-column-excel/31045900#31045900

Answer (score 1):

```
=CHAR(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)+65)
```

to be entered in B2 and pulled down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple nested IF's, given a sorted list, you could try:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,"A",CHAR(CODE(B1)+1))
```